# Logging an attribute from CSS Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

My problem is that when attempting to log an attribute from an image, when there are multiple images on the page, I am only able to log the first attribute.

## Here's a fiddle.

### http://jsfiddle.net/fauverism/b9kwT/4/

#### CSS

```
#page1, #page2, #page3, #page4 {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .active-page {
        border: 4px groove seagreen;
    }
    .inactive-page-unlocked {
        border: 4px ridge papayawhip;
    }
    .modalbg {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        z-index: 1000;
        transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    .modalbg .dialog {
        display: inline-flex;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        left: 20px;
        margin: auto;
        background-clip: contain;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
    }
    .modalbg:target {
        opacity: 1;
        pointer-events: auto;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
        transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
    }
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="main-content">
<div id="page1" class="active-page">
    <a class="magnify" href="#zoomWindow100100.GIF">
        <img id="100100.GIF-img" name="100100.GIF" src="http://placekitten.com/100/100">
    </a>
    <a href="#close" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modalbg" id="zoomWindow100100.GIF">
            <div class="dialog" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/100/100)"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="page2" class="inactive-page-unlocked">
    <a class="magnify" href="#zoomWindow120120.GIF">
        <img id="120120.GIF-img" name="120120.GIF" src="http://placekitten.com/120/120">
    </a>
    <a href="#close" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modalbg" id="zoomWindow120120.GIF">
            <div class="dialog" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/120/120)"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="page3" class="inactive-page-unlocked">
    <a class="magnify" href="#zoomWindow140140.GIF">
        <img id="140140.GIF-img" name="140140.GIF" src="http://placekitten.com/140/140">
    </a>
    <a href="#close" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modalbg" id="zoomWindow140140.GIF">
            <div class="dialog" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/140/140)"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="page4" class="inactive-page-unlocked">
    <a class="magnify" href="#zoomWindow160160.GIF">
        <img id="160160.GIF-img" name="160160.GIF" src="http://placekitten.com/160/160">
    </a>
    <a href="#close" class="modal-container">
        <div class="modalbg" id="zoomWindow160160.GIF">
            <div class="dialog" style="background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/160/160)"></div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
function openZoomWindow() {
  $('.magnify').on('click', function() {
    var nameVal = $('img').attr('id');
    console.log("show_inline_exhibit","name="+nameVal);
  });
}

function closeZoomWindow() {
  $('.modal-container').on('click', function() {
    var nameVal = $('.modalbg').attr('id');
    console.log("show_inline_exhibit","id="+nameVal);
  });
}

openZoomWindow();
closeZoomWindow();
```

---

Some details...
I've tried using this in various ways to no avail. I've tried using .each() .children(). No dice. I tried using onclick to instantiate the functions.

I don't have to log the id attribute. Logging the name will work just fine.

Thanks so much for reading this and thanks in advance for helping out if you're submitting code. This has had me stumped.

Comment: `var nameVal = $(this).find('img').attr('id');` ???

Comment: Yep, that did it! I swear I thought I tried that! Thanks so much for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the element you're clicking on, so find the img inside the anchor:

```
var nameVal = $(this).find('img').attr('id');
```

Comment: Thanks again, same as above in the comments from earlier